# Xcode shell script invocation error

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I just moved over to a new MacBook Air (10.8) and a 64-bit project that compiled before gives me Shell Script Invocation Error: /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

It looks like XCode 4.6 is failing on one of the intermediate files, saying unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"' in a file ending in .sh:

> /Users/billferster/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MovingPicture-hcmztqjnatzylkburxulgmdynyqg/Build/Intermediates/MovingPicture.build/Debug/MovingPicture.build/Script-E004D330137B9E5B00FDC604.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
>
> /Users/billferster/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MovingPicture-hcmztqjnatzylkburxulgmdynyqg/Build/Intermediates/MovingPicture.build/Debug/MovingPicture.build/Script-E004D330137B9E5B00FDC604.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file
>
> Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 2

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank

Bill

Answer (score 2):

it was was it said it was. A missing "